# Getting undefined upon calling function but it doesn't happen on every call

Tags: javascript

I'm using codecademy to learn JS and I'm getting intermittent results with this function call. In some cases it displays properly but if I continue to rerun the program it will output undefined for the days called. What am I doing wrong?

James's event is: a 5K

James's training time is: undefined days

Cleopatra's event is: Cycling

Cleopatra's training time is: 40 days

Frederick's event is: a 5K

Frederick's training time is: undefined days

```
const getRandomEvent = () => {
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)

if(random === 0){
    return "a 5K"
}
else if(random === 1){
    return "Cycling"
}
else if(random === 2)
   return "Marathon"
}

const getTrainingDays = event =>{
let days;

if(event === "5K"){
    days = 60;
}
else if(event === "Cycling"){
    days = 40;
}
else if(event === "Marathon"){
    days = 250;
}

return days;
}

const event = getRandomEvent();
const days = getTrainingDays(event);

const event2 = getRandomEvent();
const days2 = getTrainingDays(event2);

const event3 = getRandomEvent();
const days3 = getTrainingDays(event3);

const logEvent = (name, event) => console.log(`${name}'s event is: ${event}`);
const logTime = (name, days) => console.log(`${name}'s training time is: ${days} days`);

logEvent("James", event);
logTime("James", days);

logEvent("Cleopatra", event2);
logTime("Cleopatra", days2);

logEvent("Frederick", event3);
logTime("Frederick", days3);
```

Comment: Because `"a 5K" !== "5K"`, so `event === "5K"` is never `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function to get the event will return `a 5K` for `random === 0` but `getTrainingDays` checks for `event === 5K`.

Fix your script to check for event `a 5K`.

You should also include a catch all else statement where appropriate.

Consider something like the following:

```
const getRandomEvent = () => {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    if (random === 0) { 
        return "a 5K"
    } else if (random === 1) {
        return "Cycling"
    } else if(random === 2) { 
        return "Marathon"
    }
}

const getTrainingDays = event => {
    let days; 
    if (event === "a 5K") { 
        days = 60; 
    } else if (event === "Cycling") {
        days = 40; 
    } else if (event === "Marathon") {
        days = 250;
    } else {
        days = -1;
    }
    return days;
}
```

Comment: One stupid change I made on here just caused me 30 minutes of rechecking my code :|. Thank you for the help